# How to capture a Powershell CmdLet's Object output when the CmdLet is programmatically Invoked from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, pshost

## Background

- PowerShell 3 with SDK
- C# with Framework 4.5

## Implementation

I have implemented my own **PSHost** alogn with **PSHostUserInterface**.
In **PSHostUserInterface** I override all *Write...* methods and colleting the to one variable which serves the output.

## Problem

In my application I calling Cmdlets which use *WriteObject* as their output. In the *PSHostUserInterface.Write...* methods I am getting everything but these *WriteObject*'s output.
For example, I see this in regular PowerShell:

> This is sample string output from the command
>
> Here we have object from Cmdlet.WriteObject function
>
> This is another string output from the command

This is what I get in my custom PSHost in my application:

> This is sample string output from the command
>
> This is another string output from the command

## Question

How can I get in C# all the outputs of the Cmdlet?

Many thanks

Comment: Normally the return from [`Pipeline.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.invoke(v=vs.85).aspx) is an enumerable over the output from the pipeline (for error output use the `Error` property of the same `Pipeline` instance). So please update your question with the code you are using to execute PSH pipelines in your host.

Comment: Hi, there are no `Error` in the pipeline at all. I cannot just simply `Pipeline.Invoke` as my CmdLets requires UI. Because of that doing it through custom `PSHost`, `PSHostUserInterface` where I can override user interaction and execute them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Richard is onto it with his comment. If you are calling the cmdlets by using `Pipeline.Invoke()`, you have to either:

- A) Call Pipeline.Invoke again with those objects and pipe them into `Out-Default` or
- B) Just append the command `Out-Default` to the original pipeline.  This will tell PowerShell to send the output to the display (and use the default formatting).

Normally, when you stash the resulting objects that are output by a pipeline, either in a PowerShell variable `$res = Get-Process` or in C# as output from `Invoke()`, you are dealing with the actual .NET objects.  The formatting & rendering of those objects to the host is another step that PowerShell will do for you if the pipeline output is not captured.  PowerShell effectively appends a `| Out-Default` to the pipeline in this case.

Comment: Adding `Out-Default` helped. Hmmm, wondering why `Out-String` didn't helped... I also give a try to this "you are dealing with the actual .NET objects". Thank you very much, marking as an answer.

Comment: When you use `Out-Default` PowerShell will render the objects to a string and then write to the host.  With `Out-String` PowerShell will render the objects to a string and return that string as the pipeline output. It's up to you then to display it after it is returned from pipeline.Invoke().